# bash expr calculation with variables (cygwin)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, variables, cygwin

I am trying to calculate the difference between two unix timestamps. The calculation of 42-23 is for testing purposes only.

```
# !/bin/bash
TARGET=1305281500
CURRENT=`date +%s`
echo $TARGET
echo $CURRENT
A=`expr 42 - 23`
B=`expr $TARGET - $CURRENT`
echo "A: $A"
echo "B: $B"
```

Output:

```
1305281500
1305281554
expr: non-integer argument
A: 19
B:
```

What is the problem with subtracting one variable from another? The script is working on a unix maschine. I am using Cygwin on Windows 7:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 mypcname 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) 2011-03-29 10:10 i686 Cygwin

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
```

Comment: What bash version, as displayed by `bash --version` are you on?

Comment: @Neil I am using bash version 4.1.10(4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I wrote the script on Windows with its system-specific line ending `\r\n`. After changing to the Unix line ending `\n`, it works.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call `expr` for this actually just use bash's `$(( expr ))` feature. On my cygwin this code is working fine:

```
# !/bin/bash
TARGET=1305281500
CURRENT=`date +%s`
echo $TARGET
echo $CURRENT
B=$((CURRENT - TARGET))
echo "B: $B"
# For validation only
echo "$TARGET $CURRENT" | awk '{print ($2-$1)}'
```

And it gave this output:

```
B: 8316
8316
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use $[] ?

```
TARGET=1305281500
CURRENT=1305281554
A=$[42 - 23]
B=$[$TARGET - $CURRENT]
echo "A: $A"
echo "B: $B"
```

output:

```
A: 19
B: -54
```

Comment: There is no benefit in using the non-standard `$[...]` instead of the standard `$((...))`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this problem on Linux here. But do you get the right answer with the line

```
B=`expr $TARGET - $CURRENT`
```

replaced by

```
B=`eval expr $TARGET - $CURRENT`
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. Maybe it's more a problem with cygwin or my x64 architecture...